# Assign Target Group to existing ASG

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-sdk-js

I have the following code:

```js
    this.nlb = new NetworkLoadBalancer(
      this.parent,
      this.id,
      {
        vpc: this.vpc,
        vpcSubnets: {
          subnets: subnets,
        },
        internetFacing: true,
      }
    );

    const targetGroup = new NetworkTargetGroup(
      this.parent,
      `${this.id}-TG-${listenerPort}-${targetPort}`,
      {
        port: targetPort,
        protocol: Protocol.TCP_UDP,
        targetType: TargetType.INSTANCE,
        vpc: this.vpc,
      },
    );

    const listener = this.nlb.addListener(`${this.id}-TG-${listenerPort}`, {
      port: listenerPort,
      protocol: Protocol.TCP_UDP,
      defaultTargetGroups: [
        targetGroup,
      ]
    });
```

It works as expected creating the network load balancer, the target group and the listener tied to the NLB.

What I cannot accomplish is adding this new TG to an existing AutoScaling Group.

The ASG is managed by a different project, but I need to add my TG to it.

If I try:

```js
    const asg = AutoScalingGroup.fromAutoScalingGroupName(
      this.parent,
      `${this.id}-ASG-${listenerPort}-${targetPort}`,
      config.autoScalingGroup, // This has the name of the autoscaling group
    );

    const targetGroup = new NetworkTargetGroup(
      this.parent,
      `${this.id}-TG-${listenerPort}-${targetPort}`,
      {
        port: targetPort,
        protocol: Protocol.TCP_UDP,
        targets: [asg], // Add the imported ASG as target
        targetType: TargetType.INSTANCE,
        vpc: this.vpc,
      },
    );
```

It does not work because the imported SG does not offer the right methods.